# What does this size_t in the lambda do? C++ code

Tags: c++, lambda, syntax, size-t

I'm new to programming in C++, and I came across this syntax. Could someone explain the point of the size_t in this syntax?

```
// Close the file stream.
.then([=](size_t)
{
    return fileStream->close();
});
```

Comment: The lambda takes a parameter of type `size_t`. It doesn't actually use that parameter, so it's not even given a name. Presumably, the calling code expects a function taking a parameter in that spot.

Answer (score 1):

It's the type of the argument passed to the function. The argument is not used in the function. Hence, it is not named. Only the type of the argument is there.

The type of the argument is there presumably because the client to which the lambda expression is passed expects it to have an argument of type `size_t`. The client has no way of knowing how the argument is used in the lambda expression or whether it is used at all.

Comment: I understand that it's a type, but if it's not used in the function, and is therefore not named, what's the point of having it there?

Comment: @ColinSivak, it is used by a client that expects the function to take an argument. It's not the client's responsibility to figure out how the argument is used or if it is used at all.

Comment: I would suggest to read a bit of documentation about lambdas. For example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score 0):

This is like callbacks where your callback receive data from the caller and you do whatever you want with the data .
So if you don't need the data you can skip naming the parameter as it's unreferenced
You can see more examples about callbacks by reading the documentation of some winapi functions especially which enum things . e.g EnumWindows , EnumChildWindows EnumProc ....

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the lambda expression

```
[=](size_t)
{
    return fileStream->close();
}
```

is being passed to a method call

```
.then()
```

To shed some additional light: usually, a method called `.then()` is part of a Futures callback interface. The `then()` method is called on a `Future<T>` object, where `T` is some type. It will expect a callback parameter. This causes callback chaining: when the `Future<T>` is fulfilled, we will have a `T`, and at this point in time the callback is invoked with that `T`.

In your case, `T = size_t`. So presumably, the `Future` object that `.then()` is called on returns a `size_t`, which is then passed to the lambda `[=] (size_t) { ... }`. The lambda then discards the `size_t` because it doesn't need it.

What's the point of taking the `size_t` parameter if it doesn't need it? Well, maybe the original `Future` object was some kind of read call, and it stored the result somewhere else (i.e. the work is done by side-effect) and returned the number of bytes it read (the `size_t`). But the callback is just doing some cleanup work and doesn't care about what was read. It would be like the following synchronous code:

```
size_t readFile(char* buf) {
    // ... store stuff in buf
    return bytesRead;
}

auto closeFileStream(size_t) {
    return fileStream->close();
}

closeFileStream(readFile(&buf));
```

In terms of Futures, it's probably something more like:

```
Future<size_t> readFile(char* buf) {
    // ... asynchronously store stuff in buf
    // and return bytesRead as a Future
}

auto closeFileStream(size_t) {
    return fileStream->close();
}

readFile(&buf)
    .then(closeFileStream)
    .get(); // wait synchronously
```